# system call in c++ opens a new terminal . windows

Tags: c++, system

I am trying out system command in c++ .

```
std::string cmd = " DIR > d:\a.txt" ; 
int isystemOut2 = system (cmd.c_str());
```

When I run it  , I  see that d:\a.txt has the right output but I see a command prompt open and close immediately . Is there a way to stop that opening of a new command prompt .

Comment: Add `std::cin.get()` to prevent it from exiting immediately.

Comment: Are you calling `system` from a console application or a gui application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a windows API function. For example [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
STARTUPINFOW si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if (CreateProcessW(cmd, arg, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```